# Why tableView is not allowing to scroll to see the footerView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have set a custom footer for tableView via property:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [self myCustomFooterView];
```

The tableView fills almost full height in screen, so only 1/3 part of the footer is visible at the bottom. I have disabled bouncing and I can't scroll tableView to bottom to see footerView. If bouncing enabled then I can bounce and see table footer, but table returns to the same position after bounce. It looks like tableView content size does not include my footerView, and that's why I'm unable to scroll. Ay ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Did you set frame (especially height) of your footer view before setting it as the table's footer? Also try to set your footer in `viewWillAppear` and see what happens

Comment: Yes, I have set its frame to contain two actions buttons. Checked its frame via NSLog and also added red bg color to see the frame size.

Comment: Check the table view's frame and make sure it isn't bigger than the screen.

Comment: @JoshHinman Nop, it's smaller (412)

Comment: @JoshHinman You was right. I'm reusing MyViewController containing tableView in AnotherViewController by adding MyViewController.view to AnotherViewController.view as a subview. Because AnotherViewController.view contains some logo image, MyViewController.view.tableView is pushed to the bottom. As you pointer out, the problem is I have pushed tableView too much. Thanks. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Make sure to initialize `self.tableview.tableFooterView` with `initWithFrame` or a view that has height properly set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JoshHinman is right ("Check the table view's frame and make sure it isn't bigger than the screen."). I'm reusing MyViewController containing tableView in AnotherViewController by adding MyViewController.view to AnotherViewController.view as a subview. Because AnotherViewController.view contains some logo image, MyViewController.view.tableView is pushed to the bottom. As he pointer out, the problem is I have pushed tableView too much :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the footer with this datasource method as

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Also make sure the frame of tableview is satisfyiable that the footer is visible in the view

EDIt This method helps to set footer to every section,so if you want to set the footer set to the last seection after checking the section returned in the method.

well as the asker intented this worked for me

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
[view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[self.view addSubview:view1];
[self.table setTableFooterView:view1];
```

and so check `[self myCustomFooterView];`

Comment: There are two ways how to add footer. Your suggested way allows to add footer for every section. It's possible to add it for the last section but needs a little checking. Another more cleaner way is to add footer for the whole table by setting tableFooterView property.

Comment: Still, I would prefer to use tableFooterView property for setting footerView.

Answer (score 0):

Also write following code, after you set your **footer** of `UITableView`:

```
CGSize wholesize =  self.tableView.contentSize;    
wholesize.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height + self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame.size.height;  

self.tableView.contentSize = wholesize;
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, tableView.contentSize.height) animated:YES];
self.tableView.tableFooterView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```